# outline-style: none doesn't work as a class

Tags: html, css

I wanted to apply `outline-style: none;` to all my buttons in my html page. I created a class:

```
.outlineNone {
    outline-style: none;
}
```

and assign the class to all my buttons. But it seems not be working. It seems to be only working when I apply the style inline with my html.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening?

To clarify, I want to get rid of the blue rectangle that appears after you click on a button like the image below:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried `border-style: none;`? It may be a border that is showing up that you want to get rid of.

Comment: If you remove the outine, you reduce accessibility. People who cannot use mouse but use keyboard will not know anymore on which button has the focus...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
.outlineNone {
    outline-style: none !important;
}
```

It seems to be a problem with some other structure which is modifying the outline-style that has bigger priority than just a class. (it can be an ID or the Button class itself)

Answer (score 3):

instead `outline-style` just use `outline`, plus you can reset the `button` style even more by setting `border` to 0

like this:

```css
.outlineNone {
    outline:0;
    border:0;
}
```